# Oracle: Get the smaller values and the first greater value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this;

```
ID     Name     Value
1      Sample1     10
2      Sample2     20
3      Sample3     30
4      Sample4     40
```

And I would like to get all of the rows that contain smaller values and the first row that contains greater value.

For example when I send '25' as a parameter to Value column, I want to have following table;

```
ID     Name     Value
1      Sample1     10
2      Sample2     20
3      Sample3     30
```

I'm stuck at this point, thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example, what should be the result if the value you pass in as an argument is 20? In your problem statement you mention "smaller" and "greater", but what about "equal"? Then: What if you pass in the value 25, but the row with ID=4 has the value 30, equal to ID=3? Do you pick both rows (so overall you select all four rows)? These are questions about the requirement, not about the solution. They must have a very clear answer before attempting to write code.

Comment: What version of Oracle do you use? If it's Oracle 12.1 or higher, the problem has a very efficient solution using MATCH_RECOGNIZE. If you don't know your version, run `select * from v$version`. The version is a five-part "number" as in 12.1.0.2.0.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for the reply. First, if there is a tie in the rows, then I only need one of them. Second, if I send 20 as a parameter then query must return only the first two rows. And third, my Oracle version is old one :) actually 10g (10.2.0.4.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analytic functions to the rescue!

```
create table your_table (
id     number,
value  number)

insert into your_table
select level, level * 10
from dual
connect by level <= 5

select * from your_table

id  | value
----+------
1   | 10
2   | 20
3   | 30
4   | 40
5   | 50
```

Ok, now we use [lag()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm). Specify field, offset and the default value (for the first row that has no previous one).

```
select id, value, lag(value, 1, value) over (order by value)  previous_value
from   your_table

id | value | previous_value 
---+-------+---------------
1  |  10   |    10
2  |  20   |    10
3  |  30   |    20
4  |  40   |    30
5  |  50   |    40
```

Now apply `where`.

```
select id, value
from (
  select id, value, lag(value, 1, value) over (order by value)  previous_value
  from   your_table)
where   previous_value < 25
```

Works for me.

```
id  | value
----+------
1   | 10
2   | 20
3   | 30
```

Of course you have to have some policy on ties. For example, what happens if two rows have the same value and they are both first — do you want to keep both or only one of them. Or maybe you have some other criterion for breaking the tie (say, sort by id). But the idea is fairly simple.

Comment: Than you @that-young-man!! **lag()** function do the job!! And if there is a tie, I only need one of the value, other one is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try a query like this :

```
 SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE Value < 25 OR ID IN (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM YourTableName WHERE Value >= 25 ORDER BY Value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this example showed me a way to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

in Oracle, you can try this (but see "That Young Man" answer, I think it's better than mine):

```
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ID, NAME, VALUE, 1 AS RN 
    FROM YT 
    WHERE VALUE < 25
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT ID, NAME, VALUE, ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY VALUE) AS RN 
    FROM YT 
    WHERE VALUE > 25
    ) A
    WHERE RN=1;
```

Comment: @CemKahramanoğlu  Anyway, give a look at a performances of both query (mine and the one of YoungMan) if you have a lot of records.  Both works, but I am not sure which one is the best.